# I'm getting errorError: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: i at line 7 column 5

Tags: trigger

```
trigger InsertContacts on Account (After Insert) {
    if(Trigger.IsAfter)
    {
        system.debug('new Account Record is'+ Trigger.new);
        List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact>();
        for (Account acc: Trigger.New){
            for(i=0 ; i<5 ; i++)
            {
                Contact con= new contact();
                con.Last name = acc.name+i;
                con.Account Id = acc.Id;
                con. phone = acc.phone;
                conList.add(con);
            }
        }
    Insert conList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means exactly what it says. You must declare all variables in Apex before you use them, and you have not declared `i`.

It is legal to declare loop iterators inline in Apex, so you may do, e.g.,

```
for (Integer i = 0; i < LIMIT; i++) {
```

`i` is then in scope within the loop body.

You have several other spacing errors in this code that will result in it not compiling.

Comment: still i'm getting same error

Comment: If you declare all your variables correctly, you will not receive this error. I can't really help you without seeing what you're doing with specifics.

Comment: I've corrected a typo in my original note, with apologies for confusion.